# Dired+: Copy to nonexistent directory

Tags: dired, files

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+

I try to copy a file from `test` folder to nonexistent folder **`new`**:

[image: Screen_1]

But I get this error:

[image: Screene]

Is it possible to make Emacs autocreate folder **`new`** and copy the file to it?
It would be very convenient.

(In file manager **Total Commander** it's possible. And it's very good.)

Comment: Please consider filing an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. You might want to request a user option that affects (creation of missing directories for) copying and moving files generally, i.e., not something that is only specific to Dired.

Comment: I never use before command `report-emacs-bug`. Has some kind of manual for this?

Comment: Just invoke the command, then type your enhancement request in the space provided, then hit `C-c C-c` to send the report as an email. `C-c C-c` might ask you how you want to send it. I just answer `mail-client`, to use my ordinary mail client. That pops up a new mail message, where I paste the text that I edited (it is ready to paste). When you do `C-c C-c` you'll see more help/instructions. You can also just send a mail to `bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`, which is what `report-emacs-bug` helps you do. But `report-emacs-bug` sets up the mail correctly and includes some extra info.